# mysql perl placeholder rules

Tags: mysql, perl, placeholder

MySQL, Perl

The following select works fine with no placeholders, but doesn't with placeholders.  It doesn't generate any SQL errors, but it returns all blanks/zeros - not the same counts as the same statement without placeholders.

```
my $sql="SELECT ?, SUM(IF(H1='1',1,0)) AS banner1 FROM table_name WHERE (?!='' and ? IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY ?";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

my $variable = "Q1";

$sth->execute($variable, $variable, $variable, $variable);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Am I trying to use placeholders in ways not intended?  It works when I only use placeholders in the WHERE clause.  It does not work when I use a placeholder in the SELECT or GROUP BY clause.  Is that the issue - placeholders can only be used in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use placeholders in the `SELECT` portion of an SQL statement. This is described in [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values):

> With most drivers, placeholders can't be used for any element of a statement that would prevent the database server from validating the statement and creating a query execution plan for it. For example:

```
"SELECT name, age FROM ?"         # wrong (will probably fail)
"SELECT name, ?   FROM people"    # wrong (but may not 'fail')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use placeholders to substitute a column or table name.  Even in your WHERE clause, it's not doing what you think it's doing.  When you substitute `Q1` for the placeholder, you get:

```
WHERE ('Q1'!='' and 'Q1' IS NOT NULL)
```

i.e. an expression that is always true.